# Java parser and formatter for Atom DateFormat

Tags: java, jodatime, date-format

Is there a date formatting tool for Atom Dates.

According to this link:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287

```
   Such date values happen to be compatible with the following
   specifications: [ISO.8601.1988], [W3C.NOTE-datetime-19980827], and
   [W3C.REC-xmlschema-2-20041028].

   Example Date constructs:

   <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
   <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02.25Z</updated>
   <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02+01:00</updated>
   <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02.25+01:00</updated>
```

I tried to use Joda `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();` but it seems it doesn't handle the parsing when there is no milliseconds (2003-12-13T18:30:02Z for exemple).

What is the simplest way to parse all these date formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ISO 8601 format, the standard format used in for example XML. Joda Time supports this format very well, you can just pass these strings to the constructor of `DateTime`:

```
DateTime timestamp = new DateTime("2003-12-13T18:30:02Z");
```

Works without any problems, also if there are no milliseconds in the string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be xml dateTime. Then the best choice is javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar.

```
DatatypeFactory f = DatatypeFactory.newInstance();
XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = f.newXMLGregorianCalendar("2003-12-13T18:30:02.25Z");
System.out.println(xgc);
System.out.println(xgc.toGregorianCalendar().getTime());
```

output

```
2003-12-13T18:30:02.25Z
Sat Dec 13 20:30:02 EET 2003
```

See more in API

Answer (score 0):

[`DateUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html) from Apache Commons / Lang has a [parseDate method that supports multiple patterns](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html#parseDate%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). That may work for you. (The patterns must be formatted according to the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) syntax)